# How to return a Function Interface from a static function?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am using `Function<String, String>` inside a static method that is expected to return a value

This accepts an input and returns an output, how to return the value back from the method?

```
public static String getAnimalName(String name)
{
    Function<String, String> getNameFunc = (inputName)->
    {
        return  inputName.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";
    };
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Change your function to actually return a `Function<String, String>` and then `return getNameFunc` (or `return inputName -> inputName.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";`?

Comment: Why are you using a `Function` when you are simply returning a `String`?

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing doesn't make much sense. You are declaring a `Function<String, String>` inside a function, but not use it. Also I am not sure what the purpose of the parameter is you pass to the function.

Based on your code, I identified three variants that would make sense, but from your question title I would assume you are looking for solution 1.

1. Return a [`Function<String, String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) and remove the parameter from `getAnimalNameFunction`

   ```
   public static Function<String, String> getAnimalNameFunction() {
       Function<String, String> getNameFunc = (inputName) -> {
           return inputName.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";
       };
       return getNameFunc;
   }
   ```

   and then in some other code..

   ```
   Function<String, String> nameConverter = getAnimalNameFunction();
   String name = nameConverter.apply("cow");
   ```
2. Keep the parameter, but return a [`Supplier<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) instead:

   ```
   public static Supplier<String> getAnimalNameSupplier(String name) {
       Supplier<String> getNameSup = () -> {
           return name.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";
       };
       return getNameSup;
   }
   ```

   and then in some other code..

   ```
   Supplier<String> nameGetter = getAnimalNameSupplier("cow");
   String name = nameGetter.get();
   ```
3. Return a `String` (as you did originally) and remove the intermediate `Function<String, String>`

   ```
   public static String getAnimalName(String name)
   {
       return name.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";
   }
   ```

   and then in some other code..

   ```
   String name = getAnimalName();
   ```

I am not sure which of the three you tried to achieve, but I hope this sheds some light onto the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Interface `java.util.function.Function` contains a single, abstract method named `apply`. Hence you need to explicitly call that method.

The [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) is the actual implementation of the interface.

```java
public static String getAnimalName(String name) {
    Function<String, String> getNameFunc = (inputName) -> {
        return inputName.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";
    };
    return getNameFunc.apply(name);
}
```

Note that you can simplify the lambda expression to

```java
Function<String, String> getNameFunc = inputName -> inputName.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";
```

Comment: In that case, why create a Function object in the first place and not simply implement the whole `getAnimalMethod` body as `return name.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") ? "dog" : "rat";`?

Comment: @Abra I feel like just blindly answering the question without suggesting to OP that what they are trying to do is not very sensical is against the spirit of SO